# Where did the universe get its initial momentum?

Tags: cosmology, momentum, conservation-laws, reference-frames, big-bang

If, according to Newton's third law, forces come in pairs then what about the big bang? where did the universe get that initial push/momentum?

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me: Are you asking how a "point" particle at rest can disintegrate into point particles which are not at rest? (Also, Newton's laws should not be applied on cosmological scales)

Comment: Physical laws pertain to entities *within* the universe.  The Universe isn't an entity; the universe is the totality of all there is.  Entities can have the property of momentum, the Universe cannot.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri "the universe is the totality of all there is."  That's debatable, and not only in the sense that it's something "crackpots" debate: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse

Comment: @joshphysics, there are many subjects that are debatable but pointlessly so.  Whatever term one wishes to label the concept  "the totality of all there is" with, it is still *true* that momentum is not a property of *all there is*.

Answer (score 2):

The universe as a whole is not governed by Newton's Laws. Although if you are curious about the catalyst for the big bang read about Loop Quantum Gravity. It describes the beginning of the universe as a big bounce, or the collapse of a previous universe expanding again. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bounce

Answer (score 0):

It hadn't. The metric of the space is changing, as they are described by the [Friedman-equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations). There is no explosion-like thing, it is a common misconception.